# why code generated by QtCreator and MSVC with QT VS tools are different?

Tags: c++, qt

I use Qt template "Qt Widgets Application" in Qt Creator and in MSVC with QT VS tool installed. However, I found the code generated in these two are different. For instance, #include  in QtCreator becomes #include <QtWidgets/QMainWindow> in MSVC , #include  in QtCreator becomes #include <QtWidgets/QApplication> in MSVC. Also, in Qt Creator, there is ui->setupUi(this), this becomes ui.setupUi(this) in MSVC.

I use Qt 5.14.1, and Microsoft Visual Studio 2019 with QT VS tool "qt-vsaddin-msvc2019-2.4.3" installed.

Comment: ***Can anybody help me if I am doing something wrong?*** You are not. There just is more than 1 way you can use a ui file. In my code I use `setupUi(this);` which is different from both of these. But I use `CMake` and Visual Studio 2019 as the IDE and no addon.

Comment: why code generated by QtCreator and MSVC with QT VS tools are different?: Because the developers wanted it, there is no logical justification.